# OpenShift 3 mkdir error for DockerFile

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-enterprise

I am trying to deploy a Springboot app from my Docker hub account (https://hub.docker.com/r/sonamsamdupkhangsar/springboot-docker/~/dockerfile/) on OpenShift.  I selected the Yaml section to paste my YAML config from my github (https://github.com/sonamsamdupkhangsar/springboot-docker/blob/master/springboot-hello-deployment.yaml)

After waiting a while I used to get a error saying the "mkdir" error failed.  Now this morning I am seeing a another error: warningThe pod has been stuck in the pending state for more than five minutes.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: The ``mkdir`` issue appears to be more related to whether your image has been setup to run as an arbitrary user ID. See image creation guidelines in https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html

Comment: If using OpenShift Online, the stuck deployment may be due to some current issues with the Starter environments. https://status.starter.openshift.com/ What OpenShift environment are you using?

Comment: I am using the free starter  openshift.com account.

Comment: Bad idea to run jre in k8s. Better to use docker's multi-stage build: Use jdk image to build 'uber-jar' and then copy it to tiny jre alpine image just to run.